# Invalid Swift Support. doesn’t have the correct file type for this location. Static libraries

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

While appstore uploading I received such error.
libmy1 and libmy2 are imported using xcframeworks.

What is it? How can I resolve it?

```
Invalid Swift Support. The file app.app/Frameworks/libmy1.a, app.app/Frameworks/libmy2.a doesn’t have the correct file type for this location. Ensure you’re using the correct file, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it. With error code STATE_ERROR.VALIDATION_ERROR.90432 for id
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?  I'm experiencing the same problem after adding an XCFramework to my project that includes static libraries (.a files).  The app works fine on device, and on simulator, but will not upload to the app store.

Comment: @SonofaBeach hi. I've just changed 'embed & sign' for frameworks property in the project preferences

Comment: I found another work around.  Instead of generating an XC-Framework directly from the static library (.a) files, I first generated individual (non-XC) Frameworks for each platform (iphoneos, iphonesimulator, macos/catalyst).  Then I generated the cross-platform XC-Framework from these individual-platform Frameworks (which include the libraries).  Worked OK after that.  Full details are now towards the end of my (exceedingly long) answer at:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434514/build-gdal-3-x-for-ios

Comment: ...it seems that even though building an XC-Framework directly from static libraries is fully supported on device, simulator and Mac Catalyst (and presumabley non-catalyst macOS), it is not fully supported by the App Store upload process.  I do not know if this is a bug, or if it is intentional.

Comment: I did the same while worked with xcframework.